# Particular answer to a differential Equation Involving Delta function and Heaviside without Laplace

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please help me find the particular answer for ODE's Like this:

$$4y''+5y'+3y+2=8h''+7h'+6h$$

$h(x)=$Heaviside function

Answer (score 1):

Set $u=y-2h$, then this new function will have the equation
$$
(4u''+8h'')+(5u'+10h')+(3u+6h)+2=8h''+7h'+6h
\\\iff\\
4u''+5u'+3u+2=-3h'=-3\delta
$$
In a next step you can also absorb the first derivative in $u$ by adding  an anti-derivative of $h$. Let $H(x)=\max(0,x)$ so that $H'=h$ and set $v=u+\frac34H$, $y=2h-\frac34H+v$, then
$$
(4v''-3h')+(5v'-\frac{15}4h)+(3v-\frac94H)+2=-3h'
\\\iff\\
4v''+5v'+3v+2=\frac{15}4h+\frac94H
$$
You could continue to absorb the singularities or directly solve this ODE with piecewise continuous right side.

---

$v$ is piecewise smooth and at least continuously differentiable in $x=0$. It solves
$$
4v''+5v'+3v=\begin{cases}-2&\text{for }x<0\\\frac{7}4+\frac94x&\text{for }x>0\end{cases}
$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3147624/stability-for-2d-crank-nicolson-scheme-for-heat-equation can you help me with this question? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might also use a slightly different approach to end up with the 2 additional equations derived by Michael.

Define the two solutions as

$y_L=A_-e^{\alpha_1x}+B_-e^{\alpha_2x}-\frac{2}{3}$

$y_R=A_+e^{\alpha_1x}+B_+e^{\alpha_2x}-\frac{4}{3}$

and write the total solution as $y(x)=h(-x)y_L+h(x)y_R$. Higher derivatives on the RHS of the differential equation would result in additional terms in $y(x)$ like $C\delta(x)+D\delta'(x)+....$. Take now the derivatives as

$y'(x)=h(x)y'_R+h(-x)y'_L+\delta(x)(y_R-y_L)$

$y''(x)=h(x)y''_R+h(-x)y''_L+2\delta(x)(y'_R-y'_L)+\delta'(x)(y_R-y_L)$

Inserting these derivatives into the differential equation will lead to

$
h(x)(4y''_R+5y'_R+3y_R) + h(-x)(4y''_L+5y'_L+3y_L) + 2+ 4 \delta'(x)\Delta y + 8\delta(x)\Delta y' + 5\delta(x)\Delta y=8h''(x)+7h'(x)+6h(x)$

with $\Delta y=y_R-y_L$. As $y_R$ and $y_L$ are the solutions for $x>0$ and $x<0$ respectively the above equation can be simplified to give

$
4 \delta'(x)\Delta y + 8\delta(x)\Delta y' + 5\delta(x)\Delta y=8\delta'(x)+7\delta(x)
$

Note that you can not simply compare coefficients here, instead
multiplication with a testfunction $F(x)$ and integration ($\int_{0^-}^{0^+}\delta' (x)F\Delta y \,dx=-F'(0)\Delta y(0)-F(0)\Delta y'(0)$) gives:

$
-4F'(0)\Delta y(0) - 4F(0)\Delta y'(0) + 8F(0)\Delta y'(0) + 5F(0)\Delta y(0) = -8F'(0)+7F(0)
$

and for arbitrary testfunctions $F(x)$ the two following matching conditions are provided

$
\Delta y(0)=2  \qquad \qquad \qquad \rightarrow\quad y_R(0)=2+y_L(0) 
$

$
4\Delta y'(0) + 5 \Delta y(0) = 7 \quad \rightarrow\quad 4y'_R(0)=-3+4y'_L(0)
$

With the two initial conditions at $x_0$ these four equations will provide the four unknown coefficients $A_+,A_-,B_+,B_-$

Answer (score 0):

We can solve an equation like this by solving the equation in "well-behaved" regions of the real line and then integrating the ODE in a region around the singular points to find matching boundary conditions.  I'll sketch out how this is done here and leave the details as an exercise for the reader.

Consider the equation 
$$
4y''+5y'+3y+2=8h''+7h'+6h
$$
The right-hand side of this equation is equal to $6$ when $x > 0$, and equal to $0$ when $x < 0$.  In these regions, we can therefore write
$$
4 y'' + 5 y' + 3y = \begin{cases} 4 & x > 0 \\ -2 & x < 0 \end{cases}
$$
The solutions to this equation will then be
$$
y(t) = \begin{cases} A_+ e^{\alpha_1 x} + B_+ e^{\alpha_2 x} + \frac{4}{3} & x> 0 \\ A_- e^{\alpha_1 x} + B_- e^{\alpha_2 x} - \frac{2}{3} & x> 0
\end{cases},
$$
where $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are the roots of the characteristic polynomial $4 \alpha^2 + 5 \alpha + 3 = 0$, and $A_\pm$ and $B_\pm$ are as-yet undetermined coefficients.

We now integrate the original ODE over the region $x = [-\epsilon, \epsilon]$:
$$
4 \left[ y' \right]_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon + 5 \left[ y \right]_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon + \int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon} (3y + 2) \, dx = 8 \left[ h' \right]_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon + 7 \left[ h \right]_{-\epsilon}^\epsilon + 6\epsilon
$$
In the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$, this becomes
$$
4 \left[ y' \right]_{0_-}^{0_+} + 5 \left[ y \right]_{0_-}^{0_+} = 7.
$$
This leads to a condition on the unknown coefficients $A_\pm$ and $B_\pm$.  Similarly, integrating the equation twice over the same region and taking the $\epsilon \to 0$ limit yields
$$
4 \left[ y \right]_{0_-}^{0_+} = 8.
$$

The two discontinuity equations above give us two equations for the three unknowns $A_\pm$ and $B_\pm$.  The other two equations are determined by imposing appropriate conditions as $x \to -\infty$;  for example, if it must approach a constant, then we must have $A_- = B_- = 0$.