# How do you prove the convergence of a finite difference scheme directly?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I've been studying the [Lax equivalence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lax_equivalence_theorem) . I've learned that it allows you to establish the convergence of a scheme through proof of stability. The Wikipedia article says that the method it's important because "it is ordinarily difficult to establish [convergence] because the numerical method is defined by a recurrence relation while the differential equation involves a differentiable function".

I used the equivalence theorem to establish the convergence of the Crank-Nicholson method in an assignment. I was wondering what a direct proof would look like (I'm assuming it depends on the scheme). Can you please provide any references for this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Convergence or divergence depends on what problem you are solving, and not just on the method itself. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks. This is for the heat equation (I'm working with the heat equation in 2 spatial variables, does that make a difference?).

Comment: Is it linear or nonlinear problem?

Comment: linear, just the standard homogeneous heat equation in 2 spatial variables;

Comment: Are boundary conditions Dirichlet, Neuman, Robin type or mixed?

Comment: They are Dirichlet

Comment: Did you read this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3147624/stability-for-2d-crank-nicolson-scheme-for-heat-equation?